# How can I implement Hunch's API in java?

Tags: java, api, hunch

I'm creating a Java application that uses [Hunch's API](http://hunch.com/developers/v1/), but the problem is I have no clue as to how I can use a web API in Java. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on what the API provides, generally you'd need a web server (like Tomcat) to run a web framework.

If it's just an api to communicate with a service via HTTP (maybe webservices) then have a look at the corresponding libraries (JAX-WS etc.).

Edit: I looked up Hunch API, and assume it is this: http://hunch.com/developers/v1/

It seems like it would return JSON encoded data, so you might use the `URL` class to read data from an URL. That data would be a JSON string which then needs to be decoded using one of the many JSON libraries out there (e.g. [JSON-simple](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/)).

Comment: I'm actually creating a desktop application sort of like Tweetdeck.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check this out as soon as I'm back home and will mark your answer as accepted if everything goes well.